# Генерация перестановок списка чисел в Python

Tags: python, list

Имеется список c повторяющимися элементами, например `[1,1,1,0]`. Нужно сгенерировать все возможные варианты перестановок данного списка без повторений и без использования библиотек. Для данного списка результатом было бы следующее:

```
[1,1,1,0]
[1,1,0,1]
[1,0,1,1]
[0,1,1,1]
```

Как это можно реализовать без помощи библиотек по типу itertools ?

Comment: Посмотреть исходники библиотеки `itertools` ))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например как-то так:

```
def permutations(iterable):
    if len(iterable) == 1:
        yield (iterable[0], )
    else:
        for perm in permutations(iterable[1:]):
            for i in range(len(iterable)):
                yield perm[:i] + (iterable[0], ) + perm[i:]

def unique_permutations(iterable):
    return list(set(permutations(iterable)))
                
print(list(map(list, unique_permutations([1,1,1,0]))))
print([''.join(x) for x in unique_permutations("вова")])
```

Результат:

```
[[1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1]]
['овва', 'ввао', 'ваво', 'авов', 'аовв', 'воав', 'ваов', 'оавв', 'авво', 'вова', 'овав', 'ввоа']
```

Comment: это работает, но я не совсем понимаю как работает yield ?

Comment: @krplnk1 `yield` возвращает результат, но не возвращает управление, функция продолжает работать, таким образом с помощью `yield` можно возвращать последовательность (грубо говоря список) результатов, каждый элемент этой последовательности возвращается отдельным `yield`.

Comment: Всё же строить все перестановки, чтобы затем выбрать уникальные - это долго и требует много памяти. Попробуйте двадцать единиц и один нолик.

Answer (score 4):

В стандартной библиотеке `C++` есть функция [std::next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation). Она по перестановке в массиве строит следующую в лексикографическом порядке. Время построения в среднем константное, дополнительная память тоже константная. Повторяющиеся элементы обрабатываются автоматически. Генератор перестановок ниже основан на этой функции:

```
import sys


def next_permutation(a):

    def swap(i, j):
        a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]

    def reverse_tail(i):
        j = len(a) - 1
        while i < j:
            swap(i, j)
            i += 1
            j -= 1

    if len(a) <= 1:
        return False

    i = len(a) - 1
 
    while True:
        i1 = i
        i -= 1
        if a[i] < a[i1]:
            i2 = len(a)
            while True:
                i2 -= 1
                if a[i] < a[i2]:
                    break
            swap(i, i2)
            reverse_tail(i1)
            return True

        if i == 0:
            reverse_tail(0)
            return False


def permutations(a):
    a = sorted(list(a))
    yield a
    while next_permutation(a):
        yield a


for p in permutations(map(int, sys.argv[1:])):
    print(p)
```

> ```
> $ python permutations.py 0 1 2 3
> 0 1 2 3
> 0 1 3 2
> 0 2 1 3
> 0 2 3 1
> 0 3 1 2
> 0 3 2 1
> 1 0 2 3
> 1 0 3 2
> 1 2 0 3
> 1 2 3 0
> 1 3 0 2
> 1 3 2 0
> 2 0 1 3
> 2 0 3 1
> 2 1 0 3
> 2 1 3 0
> 2 3 0 1
> 2 3 1 0
> 3 0 1 2
> 3 0 2 1
> 3 1 0 2
> 3 1 2 0
> 3 2 0 1
> 3 2 1 0
>
> $ python permutations.py 0 1 1 1
> 0 1 1 1
> 1 0 1 1
> 1 1 0 1
> 1 1 1 0
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Итеративный [подход](https://www.quickperm.org/quickperm.php):

```
s = [ 1, 2, 3, 4]
p = [ 0 for _ in s ]
i = 1
res = []

while i < len(s):
    if p[i] < i:
        j = 0 if i % 2 == 0 else p[i]
        s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
        p[i] += 1
        i = 1
        if s not in res: 
            res.append(list(s))
    else:
        p[i] = 0
        i += 1

res  # [[1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1]]
```

Или же всё-таки:

```
import itertools

list(set(itertools.permutations([1, 1, 1, 0])))
# [(1, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1, 1)]
```

Comment: Ага. Ваш ответ очень подходит к условию из вопроса: "Как это можно реализовать без помощи библиотек по типу itertools". ;)

Comment: @GrAnd, а. ага. Заголовок только прочитал :) невнимательный .. Позже допишу без итертулс